# How to reset activated remote config values

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-remote-config

Using Firebase, after I fetch and activate my remote config values, calling `configValue(forKey key: String?)` will give me the value from the remote source. I know I can call `func configValue(forKey key: String?, source: RemoteConfigSource)` or `defaultValue(forKey key: String?)` to get the default value. But, how do I reset my activated data so that calling `configValue` will give me the default values again?

Further, do the activated values persisted ever get purged?

Comment: The Android SDK has a [`reset` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/remoteconfig/FirebaseRemoteConfig.html#reset()) that seems to do precisely what you want. But I don't see an equivalent method in the [Swift API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseremoteconfig/api/reference/Classes/RemoteConfig). I'll ask around...

Comment: Btw: there is a method to [get the default value for a specific parameter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseremoteconfig/api/reference/Classes/RemoteConfig#/c:objc(cs)FIRRemoteConfig(im)defaultValueForKey:namespace:). It's not exactly what you asked for, but might allow you to implement the use-case differently.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Firebaser here with some additional info that could be helpful.*

The Android SDK does have a [`reset` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/remoteconfig/FirebaseRemoteConfig.html#reset()) as of the v2 release that can do what you're looking for here. The `reset()` call will reset Remote Config to the state when it was first installed, and then you can call setDefaults() to reset to the default values and continue using them. From that point if you want to keep using these default values, you would want to avoid calling activate and fetch. Once you make those calls, the default values may get updated at the initial fetch call or following fetch intervals.

Also, the `reset()` isn't available in the iOS v2 SDK today, but it sounds like a reasonable request. Could you [please file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/features/) if this feature would be helpful for you?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. If their API supports it then all their language implementations should as well.